# PHP -> passing data to ASP's mvc and getting JSON back?

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a ASP.NET-MVC site somewhere that is supposed to take in some data and return a JSON object. Seems to work manually, i.e. if I type the data into the window and press "send", it return the needed json object.

But how should I do it from PHP ?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tool such as fiddler (or FireBug on Firefox) to inspect the HTTP request and simulate the same request in the PHP code.

The ASP.NET MVC site may use [anti-forgery token](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx) to prevent CSRF attacks - in such case, you don't have much choice but to first make the request to the page, scavenge the token and then generate your actual request.